# Cannot cast derived type to base type?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have the following setup:

```
struct Item { }

class Entry : List<Item> { }
```

in a generic class, where i pass `Entry` as type parameter, i am trying to get `List<Item>.Count`.

i have tried the following already:

```
var c = typeof(T).GetProperty("Count").GetMethod.Invoke(X, new object[]{}); // x is the variable in the generic class of type T!
```

i also tried

```
var c = (x as ICollection).Count;
// throws Cannot cast '((Entry)X)' (which has an actual type of 'Entry') to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>'
```

now i really have no idea how to get the Count :(

Code for the generic class: The idea is to have a field which remembers a specific starting value and then gives feedback if it has been changed.

```
SyncField<T>
{
    T O { get; private set; }
    T V { get; private set; }

    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (V != null && O != null)
            {
                var func = typeof(T).GetProperty("Count");
                if (func != null)
                {
                    var oc = func.GetMethod.Invoke(O, new object[] { });
                    var vc = func.GetMethod.Invoke(V, new object[] { });
                    return oc != vc; // here i am trying to simply do ICollection.Count != ICollection.Count
                }
            }
            return O != null && !O.Equals(V);
        }
    }
```

}

Update:
I settled for this:

```
public bool HasChanged
{
    get { return return O != null && !O.Equals(V); }
}
```

Why? because the `Equals()` Method of `List<T>` already does what i need to tell me if those 2 are different :)

Comment: Why are you using reflection in the first place?  If the item is an `Entry` or any subtype of it then you can just call `Count` on it and be done.

Comment: Design pattern: Favor object composition over class inheritance, why would you derive from it, instead of include a list as a member?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. (And then consider redesigning, as suggested.)

Comment: you need to tell the compiler that T is an Enumerable type by using a where clause. Then stop using reflection

Comment: @pm100 the idea for the class is to work with every type, and if its a IColecction then it shall check the count for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're doing `SyncField<Entity>` elsewhere.

```
SyncField<T>
{
    T O { get; private set; }
    T V { get; private set; }

    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (V != null && O != null && O is ICollection)
            {
                return ((ICollection)O).Count != ((ICollection)V).Count;
            }
            else
            {
                return O != null && !O.Equals(V);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assuming right :) and funny that that works, because it won't work with `as ICollection`. Thanks!

Comment: @Nefarion - I'm glad it helped.  `return (O as ICollection).Count != (V as ICollection).Count` works just fine for me, though.